# why we are using strategy.num_replicas_in_sync

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Can anybody tell me the function of the below code? I know it is used with batch size but what is it exactly calculating. Can anybody tell me, please?

```
BATCH_SIZE = 8* strategy.num_replicas_in_sync
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, on a single machine with 1 GPU/CPU, loss is divided by the number of examples in the batch of input.

So, how should the loss be calculated when using a tf.distribute.Strategy?

For an example, let's say you have 4 GPU's and a batch size of 64. One batch of input is distributed across the replicas (4 GPUs), each replica getting an input of size 16.

The model on each replica does a forward pass with its respective input and calculates the loss. Now, instead of dividing the loss by the number of examples in its respective input (BATCH_SIZE_PER_REPLICA = 16), the loss should be divided by the GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE (64).

Why do this?

This needs to be done because after the gradients are calculated on each replica, they are synced across the replicas by summing them.

See here - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training#define_the_loss_function